# storing iterating results from a single function

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I'm trying to store all 30 iterations of the same function in the same dataframe. For some reason my dataframe only contains one iteration. Do i need to do an iteration on the 'result' output? my code is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath, index_col = None)

def find_peaks(x_data, y_data):
    y_data = np.where(y_data > 5000, y_data, 0.1)
    grad = np.diff(y_data)
    peaks=[]                                   
    i = 0                                       
    while i < len(grad[:-1]):                   
        if grad[i] > 0:                        
            start = i                           
            peak_index = find_peak(start, grad) 
            end = find_end(peak_index, grad)    
            area = np.trapz(y_data[start:end], x_data[start:end]) 
            peaks.append((x_data[peak_index], y_data[peak_index], area))  
            i = end - 1             
        else:
            i+=1                              
    return peaks

for i in range(1,31):
    result = find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(result)

print df2
```

out:

```
        0          1             2
0   3053.6   105000.0  -5217775.735
1   3015.9    81892.0  -4013311.400
2   2962.8    98694.0  -2050799.050
3   2936.2    67884.0  -1140645.600
4   2906.3  2530000.0 -22099575.600
5   2871.5   102000.0   -653778.650
6   2777.9     8482.4    -68580.440
7   2719.3    11768.0    -91285.610
8   2625.0     5902.5    -40623.500
9   2599.3     5304.7    -69163.680
10  2573.5    18009.0   -170745.690
11  1538.0    12694.0   -965128.025
12  1467.7     9279.2   -144139.995
13  1451.4    21626.0   -280386.495
14  1329.8     7739.9    -63603.430
15  1173.9     8096.7    -66836.410
16   966.3    10964.0   -101197.010
17   799.2    32662.0   -305534.340
18   164.5   124000.0  -1579972.665
```

This is only one iteration. Is there something obvious I am missing?

I can create a dataframe and print it in the for loop as follows:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    result = find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(result)
    print df2
```

out:

```
0   3053.3   105000.0  -5264681.265
1   3016.0    82135.0  -3996564.000
2   2962.8    99083.0  -2068656.650
3   2936.2    68118.0  -1144331.400
4   2906.3  2540000.0 -12448747.450
5   2871.3   102000.0   -676631.550
6   2777.9     8518.1    -68760.440
7   2719.3    11823.0    -91604.700
8   2625.0     5944.9    -40842.200
9   2598.3     5341.4    -69304.580
10  2573.5    18013.0   -171000.100
11  1538.9    12768.0   -963665.665
12  1467.7     9313.0   -140466.955
13  1451.4    21736.0   -282040.645
14  1329.9     7766.8    -64290.480
15  1173.8     8124.5    -66890.800
16   966.3    10992.0   -101581.670
17   799.2    32813.0   -306268.920
18   165.1   125000.0  -1518163.855
         0          1             2
0   3053.5   107000.0  -5341438.795
1   3015.8    83495.0  -4095259.900
2   2962.6   101000.0  -1192498.950
3   2936.2    69227.0  -1158840.650
4   2906.3  2590000.0 -22633675.700
5   2871.4   104000.0   -678075.650
6   2777.9     8664.1    -71047.000
7   2719.3    11970.0    -94091.010
8   2625.0     6062.4    -43625.710
9   2599.0     5396.6    -85182.360
10  2573.5    18324.0   -175058.890
11  1539.3    12990.0   -976482.225
12  1467.7     9439.5   -144544.535
13  1451.4    22168.0   -287473.935
14  1329.8     7876.6    -65722.160
15  1173.9     8271.3    -69162.670
16   966.2    11175.0   -104500.590
17   799.2    33359.0   -312364.800
18   164.7   126000.0  -1590673.985
         0          1             2
0   3053.4   105000.0  -5251114.775
1   3015.6    82076.0  -4009585.150
2   2962.8    98884.0  -2072324.600
3   2936.2    67976.0  -1147359.800
4   2906.3  2540000.0 -22141112.700
5   2871.3   102000.0   -676034.450
6   2835.5     5922.0    -52541.315
7   2777.9     8499.6    -68753.590
8   2719.3    11826.0    -92101.350
9   2624.9     5973.3    -40374.010
10  2599.4     5334.5    -70866.150
11  2573.5    18080.0   -171285.830
12  1536.7    12711.0   -986090.675
13  1467.7     9281.1   -148301.345
14  1451.4    21621.0   -280091.420
15  1329.8     7723.2    -62916.410
16  1173.9     8101.7    -66870.850
17   966.3    11012.0   -101670.860
18   799.2    32737.0   -306106.330
19   164.9   121000.0  -1517466.745
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5266423.625
1   3016.0    82644.0  -4073279.700
2   2962.8    99532.0  -2060277.500
3   2936.2    68554.0  -1146571.550
4   2906.4  2560000.0 -12269729.200
5   2871.5   103000.0   -659901.500
6   2777.9     8576.3    -70258.860
7   2719.3    11861.0    -92537.130
8   2625.0     5996.9    -42155.310
9   2599.2     5337.1    -75180.410
10  2573.5    18094.0   -172402.780
11  1536.4    12806.0   -996597.325
12  1467.8     9338.6   -141607.480
13  1451.5    21850.0   -282960.420
14  1329.9     7786.9    -63955.860
15  1173.8     8170.9    -67855.160
16   966.3    11090.0   -102342.550
17   799.2    33048.0   -308337.090
18   165.0   127000.0  -1541565.995
         0          1             2
0   3053.8   106000.0  -5227895.505
1   3016.3    82252.0  -4041714.650
2   2962.8    99252.0  -2068891.400
3   2936.2    68293.0  -1142098.500
4   2906.4  2550000.0 -12225484.750
5   2871.6   103000.0   -647924.800
6   2777.9     8540.5    -69038.240
7   2719.3    11868.0    -92378.180
8   2624.9     5951.6    -40822.570
9   2599.2     5340.6    -71906.480
10  2573.5    18078.0   -171680.150
11  1536.5    12812.0   -992674.925
12  1467.7     9319.3   -142013.155
13  1451.4    21797.0   -282878.100
14  1329.9     7768.6    -63744.750
15  1173.9     8115.4    -66986.810
16   966.2    11044.0   -101923.130
17   799.2    32852.0   -307205.630
18   165.0   127000.0  -1535242.695
         0          1             2
0   3053.3   105000.0  -5272282.375
1   3016.0    82104.0  -4056633.200
2   2962.8    98982.0  -2045289.400
3   2936.2    68047.0  -1144401.250
4   2906.3  2540000.0 -12453831.150
5   2871.3   102000.0   -676913.250
6   2777.9     8541.3    -68876.700
7   2719.3    11793.0    -91510.060
8   2624.9     5955.1    -40273.660
9   2599.3     5324.5    -72313.440
10  2573.5    18027.0   -171148.290
11  1536.1    12724.0   -994381.815
12  1467.7     9312.6   -144574.545
13  1451.4    21750.0   -282105.360
14  1329.8     7751.1    -63726.170
15  1173.9     8127.7    -67032.530
16   966.2    11037.0   -102581.530
17   799.2    32751.0   -306267.150
18   164.7   124000.0  -1553345.655
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5265189.215
1   3016.0    82688.0  -4036892.550
2   2962.8    99517.0  -2069015.050
3   2936.2    68500.0  -1151194.550
4   2906.4  2560000.0 -12267708.100
5   2871.5   103000.0   -660027.000
6   2836.0     5955.5    -52472.160
7   2777.9     8564.5    -70173.640
8   2719.3    11870.0    -92484.110
9   2624.9     5982.4    -40998.670
10  2599.1     5356.2    -74299.320
11  2573.5    18068.0   -172105.180
12  1536.6    12815.0  -1533879.740
13  1467.7     9355.2   -143629.490
14  1451.4    21794.0   -283170.690
15  1329.9     7793.6    -64542.480
16  1173.8     8173.6    -67396.560
17   966.3    11094.0   -102249.720
18   799.2    33038.0   -308504.080
19   164.6   126000.0  -1574569.585
         0          1             2
0   3053.5   105000.0  -5231625.195
1   3015.7    81935.0  -4022440.400
2   2962.8    98586.0  -2053660.550
3   2936.2    67986.0  -1137495.700
4   2906.2  2530000.0 -22122602.300
5   2871.4   102000.0   -665178.600
6   2777.9     8478.3    -68021.330
7   2719.3    11841.0    -91483.290
8   2625.0     5918.1    -39070.060
9   2599.7     5311.7    -67478.330
10  2573.5    17936.0   -169218.520
11  1536.8    12678.0   -982684.305
12  1467.7     9274.0   -140698.360
13  1451.5    21654.0   -280552.405
14  1329.9     7742.2    -63104.470
15  1173.9     8095.0    -66294.820
16   966.3    10966.0   -101201.140
17   799.2    32731.0   -305697.550
18   165.3   127000.0  -1486712.525
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5274665.865
1   3016.1    82674.0  -4071774.300
2   2962.8    99558.0  -2066219.100
3   2936.2    68496.0  -1146350.850
4   2906.4  2560000.0 -12278707.700
5   2871.4   103000.0   -670961.150
6   2777.9     8560.6    -69495.830
7   2719.3    11880.0    -92625.860
8   2625.0     5993.5    -41590.530
9   2599.2     5346.2    -73230.510
10  2573.5    18136.0   -172528.610
11  1539.4    12772.0   -958919.915
12  1535.9    12768.0    -12767.900
13  1467.7     9347.7   -139666.010
14  1451.4    21809.0   -282404.725
15  1329.8     7789.6    -63997.730
16  1173.9     8130.6    -67136.140
17   966.3    11016.0   -101790.200
18   799.2    32893.0   -307478.280
19   164.7   123000.0  -1558789.125
         0          1             2
0   3053.5   107000.0  -5345089.435
1   3015.7    83656.0  -4118951.550
2   2962.5   101000.0  -1202811.850
3   2936.2    69268.0  -1164345.750
4   2906.3  2590000.0 -22621991.900
5   2871.4   104000.0   -677872.950
6   2777.9     8667.3    -71646.060
7   2719.3    12013.0    -94081.880
8   2625.0     6049.8    -43541.960
9   2599.1     5452.6    -83798.440
10  2573.5    18328.0   -174702.070
11  1536.6    12943.0  -1009748.295
12  1467.7     9443.4   -145409.970
13  1451.4    22013.0   -286456.020
14  1329.9     7889.0    -65194.250
15  1173.8     8249.0    -69109.850
16   966.3    11194.0   -104514.330
17   799.2    33336.0   -311816.700
18   165.5   125000.0  -1486136.215
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5275056.805
1   3015.8    82725.0  -4068048.550
2   2962.8    99561.0  -2077418.750
3   2936.2    68533.0  -1147110.850
4   2906.3  2560000.0 -12539436.300
5   2871.4   103000.0   -671279.450
6   2835.9     5963.3    -55389.310
7   2777.9     8598.8    -69739.830
8   2719.3    11854.0    -92473.400
9   2624.9     5977.1    -41511.950
10  2599.6     5361.0    -77447.630
11  2573.5    18219.0   -173562.890
12  1540.0    12806.0   -954739.515
13  1467.7     9375.3   -142509.735
14  1451.4    21896.0   -284104.170
15  1329.9     7819.0    -64769.420
16  1173.9     8131.5    -68330.980
17   966.3    11124.0   -103195.000
18   799.2    33013.0   -308627.230
19   164.7   123000.0  -1559588.815
         0          1             2
0   3053.9   106000.0  -5218189.265
1   3015.7    82293.0  -4028909.800
2   2962.8    99166.0  -2068491.600
3   2936.2    68306.0  -1147128.800
4   2906.2  2540000.0 -22238317.650
5   2871.7   103000.0   -636980.450
6   2835.9     5971.2    -57863.995
7   2777.9     8512.7    -69450.540
8   2719.3    11809.0    -92201.830
9   2625.0     5985.2    -40995.630
10  2599.2     5352.3    -73126.000
11  2573.5    18030.0   -171891.810
12  1537.8    12752.0   -975686.025
13  1467.7     9298.2   -138731.715
14  1451.4    21755.0   -282701.130
15  1329.9     7754.0    -64325.840
16  1173.9     8114.2    -66967.060
17   966.3    11050.0   -101948.170
18   799.2    32784.0   -306785.160
19   165.3   126000.0  -1497125.745
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5275229.935
1   3015.7    82698.0  -4074245.600
2   2962.8    99572.0  -2077340.800
3   2936.2    68556.0  -1146676.950
4   2906.3  2560000.0 -22320190.500
5   2871.4   103000.0   -671535.500
6   2777.9     8570.0    -69896.250
7   2719.3    11858.0    -92532.730
8   2624.9     6033.0    -41775.810
9   2598.6     5387.3    -75338.280
10  2573.5    18132.0   -172472.510
11  1539.0    12775.0   -966657.215
12  1535.5    12778.0    -29386.350
13  1467.8     9352.4   -142225.165
14  1451.4    21890.0   -285449.315
15  1329.9     7822.7    -64746.510
16  1173.8     8140.2    -67212.060
17   966.3    11083.0   -102853.620
18   799.2    33027.0   -308602.830
19   164.8   131000.0  -1578998.685
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5263073.355
1   3015.5    82580.0  -4044575.150
2   2962.8    99445.0  -2068541.250
3   2936.2    68477.0  -1145501.100
4   2906.2  2550000.0 -22300336.250
5   2871.5   103000.0   -660097.650
6   2777.9     8540.8    -69562.150
7   2719.3    11851.0    -92301.820
8   2624.9     5980.8    -41526.840
9   2599.5     5335.7    -75110.870
10  2573.5    18068.0   -171535.690
11  1538.5    12785.0   -969030.135
12  1467.7     9325.5   -142824.245
13  1451.4    21799.0   -282827.240
14  1329.9     7812.1    -64583.570
15  1173.9     8115.1    -66995.610
16   966.3    11083.0   -102866.740
17   799.2    32962.0   -307343.050
18   164.9   126000.0  -1542190.545
         0          1             2
0   3054.0   107000.0  -5254248.545
1   3015.7    83028.0  -4108625.450
2   2962.6   100000.0  -2067665.150
3   2936.2    68815.0  -1161923.900
4   2906.3  2570000.0 -12601367.400
5   2871.7   104000.0   -643512.350
6   2836.5     5988.1    -53758.345
7   2777.9     8578.2    -70396.170
8   2719.3    11910.0    -93357.430
9   2625.0     6025.3    -42258.880
10  2599.5     5387.1    -76733.960
11  2573.5    18205.0   -173865.510
12  1536.9    12929.0   -997412.535
13  1467.7     9393.4   -142291.345
14  1451.5    21926.0   -285105.860
15  1329.9     7845.1    -64911.120
16  1173.8     8214.6    -67710.700
17   966.3    11111.0   -102503.330
18   799.2    33129.0   -309381.350
19   164.8   127000.0  -1571130.525
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   106000.0  -5267792.005
1   3015.9    82644.0  -4060987.250
2   2962.8    99468.0  -2057845.450
3   2936.2    68536.0  -1157006.500
4   2906.3  2560000.0 -22307607.650
5   2871.4   103000.0   -670895.350
6   2777.9     8583.5    -69804.640
7   2719.3    11836.0    -92987.500
8   2624.9     5953.0    -41451.960
9   2599.3     5352.6    -76272.890
10  2573.5    18124.0   -172454.110
11  1540.5    12801.0   -945507.175
12  1535.9    12797.0    -28148.300
13  1467.6     9361.4   -145567.795
14  1451.4    21839.0   -283676.415
15  1329.9     7785.7    -64598.020
16  1173.9     8183.1    -67436.530
17   966.3    11139.0   -102620.090
18   799.2    32986.0   -308119.790
19   164.7   126000.0  -1572891.775
         0          1             2
0   3053.5   105000.0  -5237388.615
1   3016.1    82009.0  -4014431.400
2   2962.8    98746.0  -2049939.050
3   2936.2    67849.0  -1137311.600
4   2906.2  2530000.0 -22132482.750
5   2871.4   102000.0   -664702.900
6   2836.0     5915.9    -55276.240
7   2777.9     8458.7    -68503.080
8   2719.3    11802.0    -91989.180
9   2625.0     5934.3    -40186.620
10  2600.1     5329.6    -72514.720
11  2573.5    18007.0   -170792.560
12  1536.2    12701.0   -990763.865
13  1467.7     9302.4   -142308.070
14  1451.5    21725.0   -280484.480
15  1329.9     7724.9    -63005.910
16  1173.9     8085.5    -66164.990
17   966.3    10955.0   -101214.880
18   799.2    32674.0   -305620.780
19   164.8   125000.0  -1561357.455
         0          1             2
0   3053.4   106000.0  -5304722.875
1   3015.5    82844.0  -4074342.100
2   2962.8    99899.0  -2076876.400
3   2936.2    68785.0  -1150593.650
4   2906.2  2560000.0 -22409747.550
5   2871.3   103000.0   -681983.000
6   2836.0     5958.7    -53100.070
7   2777.9     8602.1    -70418.760
8   2719.3    11903.0    -93311.480
9   2624.9     6025.5    -41750.370
10  2599.1     5383.1    -76037.880
11  2573.5    18158.0   -172767.880
12  1537.5    12840.0   -987880.945
13  1467.7     9377.7   -143456.640
14  1451.4    21918.0   -284535.710
15  1329.8     7827.3    -64834.370
16  1173.8     8174.6    -67394.820
17   966.3    11102.0   -103079.590
18   799.2    33071.0   -308927.600
19   165.5   127000.0  -1484748.275
         0          1             2
0   3054.2   108000.0  -5282263.645
1   3016.0    83751.0  -4144337.300
2   2962.2   101000.0  -1226911.700
3   2936.2    69404.0  -1171643.200
4   2906.2  2590000.0 -22663290.050
5   2871.3   104000.0   -689998.350
6   2777.9     8693.1    -72406.270
7   2719.3    12020.0    -94385.590
8   2625.0     6073.9    -43597.730
9   2599.0     5464.3    -84262.710
10  2573.5    18401.0   -175987.390
11  1536.5    12992.0  -1017452.595
12  1467.7     9454.6   -140987.550
13  1451.4    22124.0   -288333.285
14  1329.9     7903.2    -65918.720
15  1173.9     8285.6    -69334.220
16   966.3    11237.0   -104160.440
17   799.2    33369.0   -312236.890
18   164.8   130000.0  -1572552.825
         0          1             2
0   3054.1   106000.0  -5189301.495
1   3015.8    82240.0  -4011853.800
2   2962.8    98961.0  -2064739.450
3   2936.2    68133.0  -1144886.500
4   2906.3  2540000.0 -12457070.250
5   2871.3   102000.0   -676695.700
6   2777.9     8526.4    -69498.320
7   2719.3    11777.0    -91936.940
8   2625.0     5936.6    -39681.480
9   2598.7     5348.4    -73702.570
10  2573.5    18048.0   -172057.340
11  1538.9    12763.0   -961872.385
12  1467.7     9284.1   -143518.630
13  1451.4    21726.0   -282382.630
14  1329.8     7785.4    -63853.560
15  1173.8     8137.5    -67009.300
16   966.3    11032.0   -101826.890
17   799.2    32894.0   -307287.910
18   164.7   128000.0  -1575549.575
         0          1             2
0   3054.2   107000.0  -5228854.295
1   3015.9    83051.0  -4073552.000
2   2962.8    99953.0  -2074151.350
3   2936.2    68786.0  -1160861.550
4   2906.4  2570000.0 -12319461.650
5   2871.7   104000.0   -642990.150
6   2777.8     8593.5    -70518.000
7   2719.3    11898.0    -93291.320
8   2625.0     5989.5    -42171.470
9   2599.3     5409.8    -79992.940
10  2573.5    18183.0   -173722.830
11  1537.4    12858.0   -992450.685
12  1467.8     9378.1   -142761.200
13  1451.4    21896.0   -284700.280
14  1329.9     7853.0    -64950.390
15  1173.9     8199.2    -68133.690
16   966.3    11067.0   -102855.720
17   799.2    32989.0   -308465.540
18   165.0   127000.0  -1532980.725
         0          1             2
0   3053.7   105000.0  -5205321.345
1   3015.8    81751.0  -4035781.050
2   2962.8    98485.0  -2049725.500
3   2936.2    67726.0  -1139161.450
4   2906.4  2530000.0 -12135887.450
5   2871.5   102000.0   -653477.050
6   2777.9     8481.3    -68483.020
7   2719.3    11728.0    -91079.990
8   2624.9     5908.7    -40136.220
9   2598.6     5284.4    -69483.640
10  2573.5    17909.0   -170137.490
11  1537.6    12681.0   -969209.985
12  1467.7     9229.2   -139920.115
13  1451.4    21627.0   -280030.785
14  1329.9     7729.6    -63447.630
15  1173.8     8063.4    -66632.980
16   966.3    10945.0   -100966.670
17   799.2    32577.0   -304289.400
18   164.7   125000.0  -1559196.095
         0          1             2
0   3053.4   105000.0  -5259119.795
1   3016.0    82181.0  -4039385.150
2   2962.8    98913.0  -2057664.750
3   2936.2    68078.0  -1139864.650
4   2906.3  2540000.0 -22205482.350
5   2871.3   102000.0   -676008.150
6   2836.4     5948.2    -55511.295
7   2777.9     8524.4    -69375.060
8   2719.3    11772.0    -91256.040
9   2625.0     5959.7    -40911.190
10  2599.2     5346.9    -71494.100
11  2573.5    18043.0   -171249.490
12  1536.1    12767.0  -1523369.720
13  1467.7     9250.6   -141423.685
14  1451.4    21703.0   -281430.525
15  1329.9     7736.5    -64187.780
16  1173.9     8092.8    -66922.640
17   966.3    10996.0   -101410.790
18   799.2    32704.0   -305713.600
19   165.4   126000.0  -1482283.955
         0          1             2
0   3053.6   105000.0  -5217775.735
1   3015.9    81892.0  -4013311.400
2   2962.8    98694.0  -2050799.050
3   2936.2    67884.0  -1140645.600
4   2906.3  2530000.0 -22099575.600
5   2871.5   102000.0   -653778.650
6   2777.9     8482.4    -68580.440
7   2719.3    11768.0    -91285.610
8   2625.0     5902.5    -40623.500
9   2599.3     5304.7    -69163.680
10  2573.5    18009.0   -170745.690
11  1538.0    12694.0   -965128.025
12  1467.7     9279.2   -144139.995
13  1451.4    21626.0   -280386.495
14  1329.8     7739.9    -63603.430
15  1173.9     8096.7    -66836.410
16   966.3    10964.0   -101197.010
17   799.2    32662.0   -305534.340
18   164.5   124000.0  -1579972.665
```

But, i can't export the dataframe to a csv as it only exports one loop.

Thanks,

J

Comment: You're overwriting `result` with what is returned from your func, why not do `result=[]
for i in range(1,31):
    result.append(find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)]))`

Comment: Not sure why but this is giving me 20 columns of data when there should be only 3. the 'find_peaks' function creates a list called "peaks" with three columns of data. Surely, when I 'append' this to a new list and convert to a dataframe, there still would only be three columns in the dataframe?

Comment: You need to concat the list `df = pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Comment: Sorry try `for i in range(1,31): result.append(pd.DataFrame((find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])))` and then the concat should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `result` on each iteration here:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    result = find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])
```

I suggest making a list of dfs and then `concat` them:

```
result=[]
for i in range(1,31):
    result.append(pd.DataFrame(find_peaks(df1['R'], df1['I {}'.format(i)])))

df2 = pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)
```